# How to design a request processing system calling external APIs with spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, system-design, event-driven-design

I am designing my first green field enterprise software. Users submit requests in `initial state`. Then, the system should check some required fields and might call some regulatory external APIs `asynchronously` and update the state of the request and inform the user. There are several `states` and `events` like this for the request in `accept/reject` form until it reaches the `end state`. What is the appropriate practical system design using spring boot features? I prefer it to be a `monolith` or least number of components at first and capable of easily migrating to `microservices` architecture.